# How to change email address of account owner?

Tags: here-api

This is not a technical question at all but for some weird reason your support insisted I post this question on SO...

So anyways, I would like to change the email address of my account. I do not have access to the current email address anymore. I could just go ahead and create a new account, but wanna avoid the hassle of updating API keys, etc.

I tried doing it in https://account.here.com/ but there is an error "Unauthorized" when pressing submit.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems your password is not correct or there was a typo in it when you tried? When also the email is no longer valid, then there's no way to recreate the account for security reasons. But not sure ... The HERE support may have a better idea and they should be able to help. Usually, their reply is quite fast, also on SO. Hope your issue gets fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was already an account using the email I was trying to use. A more meaningful error message would have avoided all this confusion.